# "going to" for a previously arranged future action

Tags: verb-forms, discourse-context

Aaron is carrying two tyres – he (change) 
 the tyres on a car.
Exercise on future found on lingolia

The answer is **going to** but would it be possible to use present continuous

.Aaron before changing the tyres on a car has received a phone call or the visit of a customer and they have agreed on a date, so there **is an arrangment** (at least two people are involved  the customer(s) and Aaron) made before: it has been planned.
Would it be the same with an electrician? 
Aaron is carrying electric wires he is going to change them or he is changing

Comment: There is no difference based on the nature of the agreement.  Tyres, wires, spires, flyers, driers, or even dyers, ought to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's common usage to use the "doing" verb form to mean in the future.

> Q: "What are you doing tomorrow?"
>
> A: "I'm running a marathon."

It's understood from the context that the speaker is **going to** run tomorrow.

However, when the context is unclear or ambiguous, it's better to use "going to" when describing a future event.

> Q: "What's new with you?"
>
> A: "I'm running a marathon."
>
> Q: "Uh... you're running right now?"
>
> A: "No, no. I'm going to run tomorrow!"